# How to pass the data from GET API to line 40 of this script

Tags: php

I hope someone could help me to debug this PHP script. My problem is in line 40 which corresponds to *customermobile*

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://app.snipcart.com/api/orders/76328829-55d0-4037-884b-a7413b0fa0d2',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic OlNfTW1ReVl6TmxNRGd0T0dNeU5TMDBPREZoTFRsalpXTXRNREV5Tm1ZMFlqVTFNVGcyTmpNM09UWXpPRFkyTkRrd01UazJNekEz'
  ),
));

$moredata = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $moredata;

  $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://g.payx.ph/payment_request',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'x-public-key' => 'pk_9219da5bc038b18ac8146e04f4984320',
        'amount' => '100',
        'customername' => 'Jane Doe',
        'customermobile' => ($moredata->billingAddress->phone), // <--- this is the problem
        'customeremail' => 'janedoe@fakeemail.com',
        'description' => 'Payment for products',
      ),
    ));

    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
   header('Location: '.$response->data->checkouturl);
?>
```

The field accepts up to 11 digits. I can't even pass the data from other fields like postal code.

Comment: If `$moredata` is JSON, you need to call `json_decode($moredata)` to convert it to an object.

Comment: `$more_data = json_decode(curl_exec($curl))`